# How to connect the sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is this sentence correct?
I am hesitant about the part of

> as a protein source - is it in the right place in the sentence?

And also about

> the production of which - How should i connect the second sentence with the first one?

The food industry is heavily reliant on arable crops, especially on South American soy import as a protein source - the production of which cannot be considered sustainable or environmentally responsible in the long term.

Thanks for the helps!

Comment: For comprehension, you're better off not trying to combine all that into one sentence. There are many thoughts being expressed here and trying to cram them into one sentence creates confusion.  For instance, it's not clear: is the production of all arable crops unsustainable or just South American soy? Are all steamed crops imported as protein? Or just the soy? Breaking this up will allow for clearer meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> arable crops

Arable means capable of producing crops. *arable land; arable soil.* Not *arable crops*.

> protein source

A person might consider a type of food as their source of protein. However, an entire industry... it sounds odd, even if it's logically accurate.

> soy import

The word "import" may be used as a noun, but there seem to be certain set phrases where it fits, or doesn't fit. Here "imports" would be better. "soy imports".  Or switch to "import" as a verb instead.

> length of sentence

There are too many details in one single sentence. It would be clearer if broken into multiple sentences. (by the way, what is your native language? just curious.)

Finally, here is a possible alternative wording.

> The food industry is heavily reliant on certain crops which cannot be considered sustainable or environmentally responsible in the long term. Soybean harvests, which are damaging the rain forests in South America, are a (good example/prime example of this).

Comment: I am Hungarian.